# Comunication between two indipendent node.js process

Tags: node.js, sockets, process

I've got two different and indipendent node js process running on the same server. How can script1.js send a message or better, a signal to script2.js? I won't use child process, fork o something similar because these two process are completly indipendent. A solution can be using socket but maybe there is a most lightweight way to do it. I don't need to send different type of messages, if script1 sends something to script2, it send always the same "signal", and script2 , when recieve this "signal", does always the same thing. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use child_process.fork () and the built-in communication channel.

However, if you want to use children processes, the module [node-ipc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc) could be the easiest solution for you.